# Custom admin module collection save problem

Tags: magento-1.8, module, error, adminhtml

I am developing custom admin module which save some information to custom flat table.

I have done these module before but today I am not able to save all the records from form to database table my "saveAction" not working properly.

I am not getting any error, and unable to find what is wrong with this.
Can any one check and help me, where my code is wrong.

**Mbm/Blocks/Block/Adminhtml/Blocksfrench/Edit/Tab/Form.php code**

```
protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $blocksfrench = Mage::registry('blocksfrench_data');
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('blocks_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('blocks')->__('Settings')));
        //$websiteId = Mage::getModel('core/store_group')->load($blocksfrench->getData('store_id'),'group_id');

        //$websitesThatDontHaveDonations = array(7,2,1);
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
          'name'      => 'id',
          ));

        $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('blocks')->__('Title'),
          'name'      => 'title',
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          ));

        $fieldset->addField('link_url', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('blocks')->__('Link'),
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'link_url',
          'class'     => 'required-entry validate-clean-url',
          ));


        $fieldset->addField('link_type', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('blocks')->__('Link Type'),
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'link_type',
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'values'     => array(
                            array('value'=>'Internal','label'=>'Internal'),
                            array('value'=>'External','label'=>'External'),
                          ),
          ));

        $fieldset->addField('order', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('blocks')->__('Sort Order'),
          'name'      => 'order',
          'class'     => 'validate-digits',
          ));
        $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'hidden', array(
              'name'      => 'store_id',
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('store_view_id', 'hidden', array(
              'name'      => 'store_view_id',
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('website_id', 'hidden', array(
              'name'      => 'website_id',
        ));


        $this->setForm($form);
        $form->setValues($blocksfrench->getData());
        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getblocksData()) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getblocksData());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setblocksData(null);
        } elseif (Mage::registry('blocks_data')) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('blocks_data')->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

**Mbm/Blocks/Adminhtml/BlocksfrenchController.php saveAction code**

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            $storeId = 1;
            $storeViewId = 1;
            $websiteId = 1;
            $modelSave = Mage::getModel('blocks/blocks');
            if (isset($id)) {
                $modelSave->setData($data)->setId($data['id']);
            } else {
                $modelSave->setData($data);
            }
            $modelSave->setStoreId($storeId);
            $modelSave->setStoreViewId($storeViewId);
            $modelSave->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

            try {
                $modelSave->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('customreport')->__('Store data was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $modelSave->getId()));
                    return;
                }
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $modelSave->getId()));
                return;
            }
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('customreport')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
```

**(blocks/blocks)Collection print result**

```
Mbm_Blocks_Model_Blocks Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
    [_eventObject:protected] => object
    [_resourceName:protected] => blocks/blocks
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => blocks/blocks_collection
    [_cacheTag:protected] => 
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [form_key] => apyQdrEzlH6acqb8
            [id] => 
            [title] => L'entreprise Mano
            [link_url] => www.boutikm.com
            [link_type] => Internal
            [order] => 0
            [store_id] => 1
            [store_view_id] => 1
            [website_id] => 1
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
    [_origData:protected] => 
    [_idFieldName:protected] => id
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: visit link:-https://magentomk.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/magento-create-custom-admin-backend-module/

Answer (score 0):

So basically here is what's missing in my opinion:

In your controller, under the editAction() function you should have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
$data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);

if (!empty($data)) {
   $model->setData($data);
}
Mage::register('mymodel_data', $model);
```

Then in your Form block, in the prepareForm function() you retrieve the data using a piece of code that looks like this:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getMymodelData()) {
    form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getMymodelData());
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setMymodelData(null);
} elseif (Mage::registry('mymodel_data')) {
    $form->setValues(Mage::registry('mymodel_data')->getData());
}
```

In your case, you should replace 'mymodel' with 'blocks'.

Also on a side note, I'm not sure if it's related to your problem but the following line:

```
$this->setForm($form);
```

Shouldn't be at the end of the prepareForm() function but right after this line:

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form();
```